# hot realoding in webpack dev server inside docker container on windows host dont detect any file changes

Tags: docker-compose, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload, laradock

I run docker on windows 10. I use laradock ready files for docker-compose file.
nmp run start works without any problem and compile my js files and I can watch my server on browser and devserver running simultaneously in docker container. but webpack dev server doesn't detect any file changes !
I don't want to use poll !